# Select on result of a select by filter in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table (***just for example***) as below,

```
-----------------------------
  id   name       term
-----------------------------
  1    Apple      acxxxxklte
  2    Orange     bardxxxxus
  3    Mango      fxxxxorend
  4    Grapes     laterxxxxs
  5    Lemon      spyyyygers
  6    Lime       fruityyyys
-----------------------------
```

I want to select all `id` and `name` (except `id` = **3**) from the table, having matching pattern '**xxxx**' in the `term`. My expected output is given below,

```
---------------
  id   name    
---------------
  1    Apple   
  2    Orange 
  4    Grapes 
--------------
```

How can I solve this problem using MySQL / PHP with MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use <> and LIKE:

```
SELECT id,name
 FROM example
 WHERE id <> 3
 AND term LIKE '%xxxx%';
```